# VideoWriter does not save the video correctly

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

I'm trying to use `VideoWriter` to save the retrieved frames as video file but it seems it does not work. I have checked the while loop and print the output is working. I don't know why the output of the video is only O kb.

```
 def detect_video(self, path, output_path):
    
    # Set output video writer with codec
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
        out = cv2.VideoWriter(output_path, fourcc, 25.0, (1920, 1080))
        # Read the video
        vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
        frame_read, image = vidcap.read()
        count = 0
        # Iterate over frames and pass each for prediction
        while frame_read:
            # Perform object detection and add to output file
            output_file = self.detect(image)
            #print(output_file)
            # Write frame with predictions to video
            out.write(output_file)
            # Read next frame
            frame_read, image = vidcap.read()
            count += 1
            #print(count)
        # Release video file when we're ready
        out.release()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @OrkhanAliyev I have added the more codes

Comment: Thanks for the changes. 
People should neither waste time on reproducing the code where it could be shared as text file nor try to understand what's going on there by just an image description.
Don't forget that no image description should be used for the code as the code can be shared in code format.

Comment: Your question has not a foundation I'd say. It requires more focus as followings' answer should be provided in your question: What's the problem or what are you trying to do? Can you retrieve frames from the camera and display? Does object detection works without errors and are you trying to save the video after object detection? Do you want to save the video? When it gives error and what kind of error is it? An output message or as an exception that terminates the program?

Comment: @OrkhanAliyev Thank you for your response. I am trying to save the video. The code doesn't give errors but the saved video output is only 0 kb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you didn't ask the question correctly. It has nothing to do with either TensorFlow or Object Detection. Unfortunately I got this from the comments, not from the question.

As for the problem, everything is okay but the resolution. Make sure the frame width is 1920 and the height is 1080. Otherwise, of course the video size will be 0 kb. If you've passed 1920x1080 to `cv2.VideoWriter` as output resolution, the frame size you get should also match. So, you should either resize the
retrieved frame:

```
 width = 1920
 height = 1080
 output_size = (width, height)
 out.write(cv2.resize(output_file, output_size ))
```

or use these to get the frame width and height:

```
width = vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH )
height = vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT )
fps =  vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
cv2.VideoWriter(output_path, fourcc, fps, (width, height))
```

---

P.S. Video size can not be changed while writing the video!